# Why is UIView animation not working when starting right after view is added?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, catransaction

The animation of a `UIView` should start right after the view is added to the superview:

```
class myView: UIView {
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: duration,
            delay: 0,
            options: .curveLinear,
            animations: {
                CATransaction.begin()
                CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(duration)
                self.layer.colors = [color1, color2]
                CATransaction.commit()
        },
            completion: nil
        )
    }
}
```

However, the result is that the animation is already over when the view becomes visible in the superview. `UIView.animate` does not animate but sets `self.layer.colors` immediately, maybe because the view is not yet visible when `didMoveToSuperview` is called.

How can I make the animation start normally?

Comment: Where in your view controller's lifecycle is your instance of `MyView` added to the view hierarchy?

Comment: @thefredelement overriding neither of the draw functions did help, same result.

Comment: @beyowulf Right after `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`.

Comment: Are you trying to animate a `CAGradientLayer`?

Comment: @beyowulf yes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animating gradients using core animation can be done by creating a `CABasicAnimation` and adding it to your `CAGradientLayer`. You don't need to wrap this in a `UIView` animation block and you can do this from `viewDidMoveToSuperview` provided that you add your `UIView` subclass instance to the view hierarchy sometime after your root view has been added to a `UIWindow`. For example, in a playground one can write:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyView: UIView
{
    var duration = 20.0

    var fromColors = [UIColor.orange.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    var toColors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
        animation.fromValue = fromColors
        animation.toValue = toColors
        animation.duration = duration
        gradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

        gradientLayer.colors = toColors
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let myView = MyView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(myView)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

and see a 20 second animation from vertical orange to blue gradient animate to a vertical red to green gradient.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now. The only thing to change is that the final state `gradientLayer.colors = toColors` should be set before adding the animation `gradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)`. Otherwise it would flicker sometimes when doing continuous animation. And it is not even necessary anymore to start the animation in `didMoveToSuperview`, it works also in the `init` function.